# Undefined error where calling a promoted function

Tags: go, logging, methods, struct, embedding

I am getting an `undefined` error when using a promoted function in GO.

```
import "log"
type logger struct {
    log.Logger
}

logError := logger.New(os.Stderr, "ERROR", log.LstdFlags)
logOut := logger.New(os.Stdout, "INFO", log.LstdFlags)
```

This results in compiler error:

```
logger.go: logger.New undefined (type logger has no method New)
```

However, `New` is a promoted function of the `log.Logger`. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `Logger.New()` method, only a [`log.New()`](https://golang.org/pkg/log/#New) function that returns a value of [`*log.Logger`](https://golang.org/pkg/log/#Logger):

```
func New(out io.Writer, prefix string, flag int) *Logger
```

Generated go doc deliberately lists such "constructor" functions under the type they return so you can easily find them, but this grouping doesn't make them methods. `log.New()` has no receiver so it cannot be a method, only a function.

You may use `log.New()` to obtain a value of type `*log.Logger`, which if you dereference, you get a value of type `log.Logger`, the value you embed.

However, if something is handed to you as a pointer in the first place, that is a strong indication that you should work with it as a pointer (and shouldn't dereference it). So I'd embed `*log.Logger`, methods will still get promoted (because they have pointer receiver). This is how you could initialize your loggers:

```
type logger struct {
    *log.Logger
}

var logError = logger{
    Logger: log.New(os.Stderr, "ERROR", log.LstdFlags),
}

var logOut = logger{
    Logger: log.New(os.Stdout, "INFO", log.LstdFlags),
}
```

Although if you add nothing else to your `logger` type, I don't see its existence justified, you could use `*log.Logger` as well.

Comment: Obviously you are right! How can I use `log.New()` to initialize my `logger` structs?

Comment: Nice explained. Thank you.